# Generalize algorithm for a loop comparing to last record?

Tags: python, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data set which I can represent by this toy example of a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{
        "_id" : "001",
        "Location" : "NY",
        "start_date" : "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Foo" : "fruits"
    },
        {
        "_id" : "002",
        "Location" : "NY",
        "start_date" : "2022-01-02T00:00:00Z",
        "Foo" : "fruits"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "011",
        "Location" : "NY",
        "start_date" : "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Bar" : "vegetables"
    },
        {
        "_id" : "012",
        "Location" : "NY",
        "Start_Date" : "2022-02-02T00:00:00Z",
        "Bar" : "vegetables"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "101",
        "Location" : "NY",
        "Start_Date" : "2022-03-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Baz" : "pizza"
    },
        {
        "_id" : "102",
        "Location" : "NY",
        "Start_Date" : "2022-03-2T00:00:00Z",
        "Baz" : "pizza"
    },
]
```

Here is an algorithm in Python which collects each of the keys in each 'collection' and whenever there is a key change, the algorithm adds those keys to output.

```
data_keys = []
for i, lst in enumerate(data):
    all_keys = []
    for k, v in lst.items():
        all_keys.append(k)
        if k.lower() == 'start_date':
            start_date = v
    this_coll = {'start_date': start_date, 'all_keys': all_keys}
    if i == 0:
        data_keys.append(this_coll)
    else:
        last_coll = data_keys[-1]
        if this_coll['all_keys'] == last_coll['all_keys']:
            continue
        else:
            data_keys.append(this_coll)
```

The correct output given here records each change of field name: `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` as well as the change of case in field `start_date` to `Start_Date`:

```
[{'start_date': '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  'all_keys': ['_id', 'Location', 'start_date', 'Foo']},
 {'start_date': '2022-02-01T00:00:00Z',
  'all_keys': ['_id', 'Location', 'start_date', 'Bar']},
 {'start_date': '2022-02-02T00:00:00Z',
  'all_keys': ['_id', 'Location', 'Start_Date', 'Bar']},
 {'start_date': '2022-03-01T00:00:00Z',
  'all_keys': ['_id', 'Location', 'Start_Date', 'Baz']}]
```

**Is there a *general algorithm* which covers this pattern comparing current to previous item in a stack?**

I need to generalize this algorithm and find a solution to do exactly the same thing with MongoDB documents in a collection. In order for me to discover if Mongo has an Aggregation Pipeline Operator which I could use, I must first understand if this basic algorithm has other common forms so I know what to look for.

***Or someone who knows MongoDB aggregation pipelines really well could suggest operators which would produce the desired result?***

Comment: Is pandas and a diff operator an option? Or required to be in Mongo?

Comment: That's not the goal, because if I use Pandas for my final solution then I have to query all of the documents in Mongo. I'd much rather do that in a Mongo aggregation pipeline on the sever. So the two possible answers are a generalization of this algorithm which helps me find the Mongo operators I need, or an actual solution in Mongo shell/pymongo. Pandas is cheating. hehe But nothing should stop you if you wish to contribute an awesome pandas solution. Because I love Pandas too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: If you want to use a query for this, one option is something like:

1. The `$objectToArray` allow to format the keys as values, and the `$ifNull` allows to check several options of `start_date`.
2. The `$unwind` allows us to sort the keys.
3. The `$group` allow us to undo the `$unwind`, but now with sorted keys
4. `$reduce` to create a string from all keys, so we'll have something to compare.
5. group again, but now with our string, so we'll only have documents for changes.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"},
      start_date: {$ifNull: ["$start_date", "$Start_Date"]}
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$project: {start_date: 1, key: "$data.k", _id: 0}},
  {$sort: {start_date: 1,  key: 1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$start_date", all_keys: {$push: "$key"}}},
  {
    $project: {
      all_keys: 1,
      all_keys_string: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$all_keys",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {$concat: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$all_keys_string",
      all_keys: {$first: "$all_keys"},
      start_date: {$first: "$_id"}
    }
  },
  {$unset: "_id"}
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l5DfdIm3Hm7)

Comment: _"it does return the request result"_ Your playground example is not the same as my expected output. My result only has an output when the keys (fields) change. The input set has six dicts, and the output set has four. Looking at your aggregation, and understanding @tdelaney 's solution, I don't see anything like a group stage or other mechanism to signal change in the keys/fields.

Comment: Got you now. Updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` iterates subiterators when a key value has changed. It does the work of tracking a changing key for you. In your case, that's the keys of the dictionary. You can create a list comprehension that takes the first value from each of these subiterators.

```
import itertools

data = ... your data ...
data_keys = [next(val) 
    for _, val in itertools.groupby(data, lambda record: record.keys())]
for row in data_keys:
    print(row)
```

Result

```
{'_id': '001', 'Location': 'NY', 'start_date': '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'Foo': 'fruits'}
{'_id': '011', 'Location': 'NY', 'start_date': '2022-02-01T00:00:00Z', 'Bar': 'vegetables'}
{'_id': '012', 'Location': 'NY', 'Start_Date': '2022-02-02T00:00:00Z', 'Bar': 'vegetables'}
{'_id': '101', 'Location': 'NY', 'Start_Date': '2022-03-01T00:00:00Z', 'Baz': 'pizza'}
```

Comment: So what makes this work is my orderly data (or sorted date order), a data structure which respects order, and a groupby which outputs with each change as they happen...?

Comment: Yes. It groups by the changing key. If you want that to be unique, you need to sort by the key first. In your case, that's problematic - you would have to normalize the keys (maybe sort them into a tuple first). A different way to do this is to normalize the keys and then have a dict of lists that hold the categorized data.

Comment: _"you would have to normalize the keys"_ Why normalize? My comment was a further _generalizing description_ of your solution. Are you saying `itertools.groupby` is "normalizing" something about the keys and I missed that in my description? I ask this because I don't think of this as a normalizing problem. I have a stack (database, list of dicts) and whenever the _changing key_ (dict keys or document fields) changes from the last document, I get an output. Or are you using 'normalize' in a different sense? Or in anticipation of why I need to know when a collection's fields change?

Comment: `groupby` uses equality to decide when a key has changed and `dict_keys` (the result of `record.keys()` supports the equality comparison. No normalization needed. What makes it work is your ordered data, as you said in your comment. The rest of my comment dealt with the case where your data is not ordered. If your keys transition from, say, A to B to C then back to A, you'll emit A twice. That's when either sorting or indexing your data comes into play - and that's where `dict_keys` isn't sufficient.

Comment: tdelaney and nimrod_serok both answered my question perfectly. What I know in simple loops was perfectly explained by tdelaney's  example. And now I better understand @nimrod_serok's example in Mongo. I'm going to give nimrod the "answer", because, you know 'nimrod'. hehe