# Sorted aggregation with group stage returns useless $first

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

### Data

My collection is un-nested transaction data. Once or twice a year the third party changes their schema. I'm creating what I'm calling a *schema change* table listing transaction schemas and their `effective_date`. I need to initialize this table for pre-existing data in Mongo collection.

The important features in the original data look like this:

```
[_id, ..., [...], ..., g_uploaded_at, g_unique_id]
```

(`[...]` are transaction features: `Time`, `Amount`, etc. not in the aggregation)

### Aggregation with Group stage

Based on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72325550/generalize-algorithm-for-a-loop-comparing-to-last-record) I have an aggregation pipeline which actually returns a row for each change in schema with three features in results:

- `all_keys`, a concat of all features/headers
- `g_unique_id`, some record which has these features
- `g_uploaded_at`, **should be the sorted date of the oldest/newest record**

### Problem

Results of this aggregation are **not consistent**. Recall, the goal is **define the boundary** of the schema change using sorting and grouping.

```
result = coll.aggregate([
    {'$sort': {'g_uploaded_at': -1}},
    {
        '$project': {
            'data': {'$objectToArray': "$$ROOT"},
            'g_unique_id': 1,
            'g_uploaded_at': 1}
    },
    {'$unwind': "$data"},
    {'$project': {'g_uploaded_at': 1, 'g_unique_id': 1, 'key': "$data.k", '_id': 0}},
    {'$sort': {'key': 1}},
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': "$g_unique_id", 
            'all_keys': {'$push': "$key"},
            'g_uploaded_at': {'$first': "$g_uploaded_at"},
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'all_keys': 1,
            'g_uploaded_at': 1,
            'all_keys_string': {
                '$reduce': {
                    'input': "$all_keys",
                    'initialValue': "",
                    'in': {'$concat': ["$$value", "$$this"]}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': "$all_keys_string",
            'all_keys': {'$first': "$all_keys"},
            'g_unique_id': {'$first': "$_id"},
            'g_uploaded_at': {'$first': "$g_uploaded_at"},

        }
    },
    {'$unset': "_id"},
])
```

### [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/in3ZGUlZiQ6) example

If I run this multiple times, feature `all_keys` with value `BAZ` will (eventually, keep trying) cycle through the different id's and dates in the toy data set (11 records).

Using `$first` as described here: [A: mongo group query how to keep fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662878/343215) I'm new to Mongo. Maybe a rookie mistake?

Comment: Does this help [https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-consistency](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-consistency) ?

Comment: The link says to add a unique id to the sort stage. [A first attempt didn't improve the sort](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bVBADCRRmQn). I will search for more information

Comment: I found [this on Mongo forums](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-random-documents-with-aggregate-group/16796/8) about `group` stages... Maybe I [fixed it?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_jqM4fy-Xof)

Comment: The additional "sort" you added just before the group on the `key` field is the problem, you can just use `$min` instead of `$first` if you want to keep the existing pipeline as is, by doing this you can also drop the first `$sort` stage, it might even boost performance.

Comment: `$min` sounds like a good idea. The objective is predictable and reasoned result which will inform how I use my new schema change table. Then I can do a reverse lookup (for transactions after (date) use (schema)). One thing..._"The additional "sort" ...on the key field is the problem..."_ Did you try it in the Playground example? When I remove the sort on `key` (ln 29), then i get _permutations_ of `all_keys` in the group stage (ln 34). Maybe I'm missing something else?